# What advantages provide document.registerElement()?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using own custom tag directly in HTML document without using `document.registerElement('my-tag')`
seems to works fine. It can be styled as usual etc.

Comment: Look at this article - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[registerElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement) has two advantages:

1. It returns a constructor for that tag, meaning you can instantiate it via Javascript, e.g:
   `var myTag = document.registerElement("my-tag");
   document.body.appendChild(new myTag())`
2. It provides a second parameter which allows you to select a prototype for your element, e.g.
   `var customImg = document.registerElement("custom-img", { prototype: Object.create(HTMLImageElement.prototype) });`

The second one is actually a general *options* object where an additional prototype can be extended or an *existing* tag be extended (like `<img is="custom-img">`)

Comment: So as long as developer use custom tags as relacement for div and don't need to create new markup from javascript, registerElement is unnecessary. Is it right?

Comment: @farincz Yes, but I'm not sure why you'd want to replace `<div>` anyway if the other aspects of web components aren't used.

Comment: in fact, you replacing eg `<div class="menu-item">` with `<menu-item>` which makes shorted and probably more readable makrup. I am still not convinced if I like it but at least I thinking about it as possibility.